# Uncheck always checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I am using a checkbox and I hope it is never checked.

I used a function for this, but it is not working, if you check the checkbox a few times it is active (checked).

How can I keep it always unchecked?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsm9do?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**.TS**

```
check: boolean = false;

change(e){
  this.check = false
}
```

**.HTML**

```
<ul class="mdc-image-list my-image-list" style="margin-top:120px;padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let product of data; let  j = index;">
        <li class="mdc-image-list__item">
            <div class="mdc-image-list__image-aspect-container">
                        <img [src]="product.image" class="mdc-image-list__image">
            </div>
            <div class="mdc-image-list--with-text-protection">
                <div class="mdc-image-list__supporting mdc-image-list__supporting">
                    <span class="mdc-image-list__label">{{product.name}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="Info">
                    <dx-check-box (onValueChanged)="change($event);" [(value)]="check"></dx-check-box>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

**Problem**

[image]

Comment: And you don't want to disable it?

Comment: @ConnorsFan 
I intend to click on it to extract data from the event, but I intend that it will never be checked :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[ngModel]` binding to display the `check` value and `(ngModelChange)` event handling to process the change:

```html
<dx-check-box [ngModel]="check" (ngModelChange)="change($event)"></dx-check-box>
```

In the event handler:

1. Set the new `check` value
2. Force change detection by calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges`
3. Set the `check` value back to `false`

```js
change(value) {
  this.check = value;
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  this.check = false;
  ...
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mx4ugs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried simple

```
<dx-check-box [value]="false"></dx-check-box>
```

But for me it doesn't worked.

Seems to be a bug or something.

Workaround options are:

1. `<dx-check-box [value]="false" [disable]="true"></dx-check-box>` - working, and looking a bit differently, but you can set up some styles in `css` to make it look as it's not disabled
2. paint transparent `div` over the checkbox, it prevents `input` from being clicked